# How to check registered strategies on HAPI >v20

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, hapi

I`m going to update my service from HAPI v18 to HAPI v20.1.4
On the previous HAPI version, I was able to check registered strategies using
`server._core.auth._strategies[<strategy_name>]`
For the newer version I don`t see the `server._core.auth._strategies` property specified.
Maybe somebody knows how to check it on the newest version.

Comment: did you search the docs for it? https://hapi.dev/api/?v=20.1.2#-routeoptionsauthstrategies

Comment: "Tests a request against an authentication strategy" Woud that work? https://hapi.dev/api/?v=20.1.2#-await-serverauthteststrategy-request

Comment: as I understand, auth.test() method works only inside the request handler

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause for that
`server.auth._strategies` is now a private property #strategies and is no longer accessible
The only way to check if a strategy has been registered is trying to register it one more time, it is how it looks like on the test:
`expect(() => server.auth.strategy(<strategy_name>)).toThrowError(/Authentication strategy name already exists/);`